# Make cURL with cordova/phonegap

Tags: angularjs, cordova, curl, plugins

Hi i dont find any related info about this, my question is simple, is there any way

- Plugin
- Code (Java ,C)
- etc

to make a cURL call in an apache cordova app to a custom web service, i know it sound weird but the thing is we have a service from a partner office and they didnt want/know to configure the CORS so i need to make a subservice that call they service via cURL and the send the data to the device, and seems like a lot i want to know if theres any way to achieve that in cordova, i know it cant be done in pure JS but maybe a guide or something to acomplish my goal with java or c will help, regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhoneGap API Curl from Command Line to php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265375/phonegap-api-curl-from-command-line-to-php)

Comment: No is not duplicated he wants to use a regular php cURL i want to k now a way to do that from java or a workaround that works like curl not from the php version

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process to setup a proxy service to make the call indirectly:

- Use `java.net.URL` to map the URL
- Use `java.net.URLConnection` to make the connection
- Use `java.net.Proxy` to make a proxy connection

Use the CLI in conjunction with node.js and the [ex-curl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ex-curl) module for a platform agnostic solution.

**References**

- [Networking with Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-android-networking/)
- [Cordova Guide: The Command Line Interface (CLI)](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/cli/index.html)